# cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed variable

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I am not sure what's wrong in the code.

```
public void SaveRegistration(UserRegistration registration)
{
 var result = _registration.SaveRegistration(registration);
}
```

**it showing the error as cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed variable**

Comment: If the method doesn’t return anything you can’t get a result from it. That’s what the error says.

Comment: Even if you could do this, what use would the result be? maybe you are looking for a delegate or action. Also this whole method seems suspect, please describe what you are trying to do

Comment: Interestingly enough, the error message for an explicitly typed variable is "Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to '<whatever the type of the variable is>'", even if the variable type is `dynamic`.